# Bootstrap 4 - when we should use row?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I've read essential and basic instruction of Bootstrap 4 and I have a question about it :

When we should use `.row` in our structure. Cause I've seen [this](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_jumbotron&stacked=h) and it did not use `.row` in their code. However basic structure of Bootstrap looks like `container(or container-fluid) -> row -> col-*-*` . My guess is when we use tables or Jumbotron, we shouldn't use it but I have no idea why. Is there any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using the grid system (`col-*-*`) in Bootstrap, you should use `row`s.

Your example doesn't use the grid system, so `row`s aren't needed.

The grid system is contains of 12 columns, but if you don't want for example `col-6` and `col-4` to be on the same row, you should have 2 `row`s. So you use `row` to "separate" 2 (or more) grids from together.

You can read more about grids and rows in the [docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#how-it-works).